# Import error on boto - Module not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualenv, pip

I have a ubuntu LTS server. On boot I run a script which does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
apt-get -y install python-pip python-virtualenv                                      
mkdir /etc/test/venv
virtualenv /etc/test/venv
. /etc/test/venv/bin/activate
pip install -r /etc/test/requirements.txt
cd /etc/test/utilities/                             
chmod +x worker.py                                     
./worker.py &                                          
exit 0
```

I know that this executes ok. In my requirements.txt I have the following:

```
boto
scrapy
```

Then in my worker.py it starts with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import boto.swf.layer2 as swf
```

The error I get is:

```
Import Error: No module named boto.swf.layer2
```

I don't know where to start understanding what is going wrong. Is it a path error, or is boto not being installed correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have an old version of boto pre-installed on your AMI that doesn't have SWF Layer 2 support yet.

Check by typing this into a shell:

`python -c "import boto; print boto.Version"`

I think SWF Layer 2 was added in release 2.7, anything before that won't work.
[Here's the commit adding Layer2 to SWF](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/7e318eb40309427a01f1e7f441ce5dacc800d492#boto/swf/layer2.py)

Your easiest option is to add -U to your pip command so it updates your packages if they're already installed:

```
pip install -U -r /etc/test/requirements.txt
```